# Why do I get an error when I try to use Perl's DBD::mysql?

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi, dbd

I am trying to write data to a MySQL database using Perl.  However, when I run my script I get the error below:

`Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at LargeLDAPSearch.pl line 10.`

I do have these "use" statements and following code.  This is just a small excerpt, because the script worked before I tried a DB connection:

```
use DBD::mysql;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $query_handle;

my ($platform,$database,$host,$port,$db_user,$pw) = ("mysql","results","localhost","3306","root","mysql123");

my $dsn = "dbi:$platform:$database:$host:$port";

my $connect = DBI->connect($dsn,$db_user,$pw) || die "Could not connect to database";

my $query_insert = "INSERT INTO " . $dbname . "(uid,status,lstpwdset,reset) VALUES (" . $strSAMA . "," . $strAcctControl . "," . $pwLS . "," . $reset . ")";

$query_handle = $connect->prepare($query_insert);
$query_handle->execute();
```

I have gone into my Perl folder on my local, and searched the lib file
directory.  In the `/lib/` subfolder, I have two folders, a DBI and a DBD
subfolder, and I have MySQL subfolder in DBD and also a DBD subfolder with a
MySQL subfolder under DBI.  `/lib/DBD/mysql/` & `/lib/DBI/DBD/mysql/``

This could be the error, fodlers in two spots.  I went to the CPAN website, and have tried the manual isntall steps, and i receive an install error of DBI regarding SQLLite.

Comment: Have you installed both `DBI` and `DBD::mysql`? If so, how did you do it? This error sounds like `DBD::mysql` either isn't installed or wasn't installed correctly.

Comment: When I run MakeFile.pl I get this 
`code It looks like you don't have a C compiler on your PATH, so you will not be
able to compile C or XS extension modules.  You can install GCC from the
MinGW package using the Perl Package Manager by running:

    ppm install MinGW

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Writing Makefile for Data::ShowTable
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
Press any key to continue . . .`

Run cmd to install DBI err:
`code ppm install DBI ppm install failed: install_driver(SQLite) failed: DBD::SQLite object version 1.33 does not match bootstrap parameter 1.35`

Comment: Don't cram these important bits of information into comments. Instead, edit, update, rewrite your question with the relevant bits. You seem to have borked your ActivePerl installation which uses a SQLite database to keep information on installed modules. Somehow it's loading a SQLite DLL that is a lower version than the version against which your distribution's `DBD::SQLite` was built against.

Comment: I had the same problem. But it does seem that ActiveState perl can work with DBDLite installed with it. Mine works with and without installing perl-DBD-MySQL using YUM. Also works with and without having `use DBD::mysql` in my script. I did install MySQL on the box running the Perl script (after experiencing the errors). Not sure if MySQL provided any library files etc to help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install `DBI` and `DBD::mysql` using

```
C:\> ppm install DBI
C:\> ppm install DBD::mysql
```

You seem to be using ActivePerl, so use the facilities it provides you.

[DBD::mysql](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD%3a%3amysql) does come with [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD%3a%3amysql):

> From perl you activate the interface with the statement

```
use DBI;
```

> After that you can connect to multiple MySQL database servers and send
>   multiple queries to any of them via a simple object oriented interface.
>   Two types of objects are available: database handles and statement
>   handles. Perl returns a database handle to the connect method like so:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=$db;host=$host",
                  $user, $password, {RaiseError => 1});
```

Comment: I am giving you an up and the check for this answer.  But for some reason my Active Perl Package Manager is not loading.  I have rebooted my computer, and still nothing.  I am going to uninstall it and reinstall and then reinstall the addons via CPAN.

Comment: As I said before: *you seem to have borked your ActivePerl installation. `ppm` uses a SQLite database to keep information on installed modules. Somehow it's loading a SQLite DLL that is a lower version than the version against which your distribution's DBD::SQLite was built against.*

Comment: Download version 1.35 from CPAN or another vendor?

Answer (score 4):

Do not `use DBD::mysql`. Do just `use DBI`. It will load your MySQL driver automagically.

Comment: I tried that as well before I made that post, and I get this error:
`code install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't locate loadable object for module DBD::mysql
 in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at (eval 12) line 3.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 12) line 3, <STDIN> line 2.
Perhaps a module that DBD::mysql requires hasn't been fully installed`

Maybe I didn't install it correctly.  Not sure why I got a -1 one on this question.